# TypeORM inserts an additional empty row for no reason when saving an entity

Tags: mysql, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I've been making an application for tracking user finances with NestJS, TypeORM and MySQL on the backend and all was going swell until I ran into a brick wall which was saving an entity called Financialchange which represents one unit of financial expense or gain. The problem is that in a table that represents a many to many relationship of user defined tags with the financial change, an empty row is inserted every time I save this entity along with the row that is correctly inserted.

The saving is done like this:

```
const financialChange = await this.financialChangeRepository.save({
  amount: payload.amount,
  description: payload.description,
  expense: payload.expense,
  paymentSourceId: payload.paymentSourceId,
  appUserId: payload.appUserId,
  createdAt: format(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
});

payload.tagIds.forEach(async (tagId) => {
  await this.financialChangeTagRepository.save({
    financialChangeId: financialChange.id,
    tagId
  });
});
```

An example of sent data:

```
mutation {
  addFinancialChange(
    financialChange: {
      appUserId: 1
      amount: 200
      description: "Description"
      expense: true
      paymentSourceId: 1
      tagIds: [1]
    }
  )
}
```

And when selecting data from the many to many table I get this:

[image]

The entity data is as follows, first the MySQL table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE financialchange (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  amount DOUBLE,
  createdAt DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
  description VARCHAR(255),
  expense BOOLEAN,
  paymentSourceId INT,
  appUserId INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (appUserId) REFERENCES appuser(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (paymentSourceId) REFERENCES paymentsource(id)
);
```

And then the TypeORM entity in Nest:

```
@Index("appUserId", ["appUserId"], {})
@Index("paymentSourceId", ["paymentSourceId"], {})
@Entity("financialchange", { schema: "finapp" })
export class Financialchange {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: "int", name: "id" })
  public id?: number;

  @Column("double", { name: "amount", nullable: true, precision: 22 })
  public amount?: number | null;

  @Column("datetime", { name: "createdAt", default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" })
  public createdAt?: Date;

  @Column("varchar", { name: "description", nullable: true, length: 255 })
  public description?: string | null;

  @Column("tinyint", { name: "expense", nullable: true, width: 1 })
  public expense?: boolean | null;

  @Column("int", { name: "paymentSourceId", nullable: true })
  public paymentSourceId?: number | null;

  @Column("int", { name: "appUserId", nullable: true })
  public appUserId?: number | null;

  @ManyToOne(() => Appuser, (appuser) => appuser.financialchanges, {
    onDelete: "NO ACTION",
    onUpdate: "NO ACTION"
  })
  @JoinColumn([{ name: "appUserId", referencedColumnName: "id" }])
  public appUser?: Appuser;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => Paymentsource,
    (paymentsource) => paymentsource.financialchanges,
    { onDelete: "NO ACTION", onUpdate: "NO ACTION" }
  )
  @JoinColumn([{ name: "paymentSourceId", referencedColumnName: "id" }])
  public paymentSource?: Paymentsource;

  @OneToMany(
    () => Financialchangetag,
    (financialchangetag) => financialchangetag.financialChange
  )
  public financialchangetags?: Financialchangetag[];
}
```

It is in concept defined as having N amounts of tags binded to it, which is why I have created a table that represents a many to many relation called financialchangetags:

```
CREATE TABLE financialchangetag (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  financialChangeId INT,
  tagId INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (financialChangeId) REFERENCES financialchange(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (tagId) REFERENCES tag(id)
);
```

```
@Index("financialChangeId", ["financialChangeId"], {})
@Index("tagId", ["tagId"], {})
@Entity("financialchangetag", { schema: "finapp" })
export class Financialchangetag {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: "int", name: "id" })
  public id?: number;

  @Column("int", { name: "financialChangeId", nullable: true })
  public financialChangeId?: number | null;

  @Column("int", { name: "tagId", nullable: true })
  public tagId?: number | null;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => Financialchange,
    (financialchange) => financialchange.financialchangetags,
    { onDelete: "NO ACTION", onUpdate: "NO ACTION" }
  )
  @JoinColumn([{ name: "financialChangeId", referencedColumnName: "id" }])
  public financialChange?: Financialchange;

  @ManyToOne(() => Tag, (tag) => tag.financialchangetags, {
    onDelete: "NO ACTION",
    onUpdate: "NO ACTION"
  })
  @JoinColumn([{ name: "tagId", referencedColumnName: "id" }])
  public tag?: Tag;
}
```

And the tag table is defined in this manner:

```
CREATE TABLE tag (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  description VARCHAR(255)
);
```

```
@Entity("tag", { schema: "finapp" })
export class Tag {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: "int", name: "id" })
  public id?: number;

  @Column("varchar", { name: "description", nullable: true, length: 255 })
  public description?: string | null;

  @OneToMany(
    () => Financialchangetag,
    (financialchangetag) => financialchangetag.tag
  )
  public financialchangetags?: Financialchangetag[];
}
```

I have no clue why this is, I have tried inserting a record into financialchange with a transaction manager and through other methods of saving data that TypeORM offers, but I still get an empty row in my M:N table.

Comment: When you select everything, do you get an empty row as well?

Comment: Yes. An empty row is inserted each time I add a new record into financialchange and a select returns rows with null values for each foreign key.

Comment: If you debug the foreach, it just executes once, correct? Both financialTagChange's are written at the same moment?

Comment: Can you put console.log inside the foreach loop and check the data. I think it may be some issue inside that loop.

Comment: The problem is not with the foreach loop. If I have no tagIds sent it does not iterate over anything and a null row is created regardless.

Comment: In every situation when a financialchange entity is saved, a null row is created, with or without tags.

Comment: maybe try to make the field not nullable for debug purposes, u'll see the exact moment of failure than, which could give new clues

Comment: I did. It was not NOT NULL before, but in that case it tried to do this statement while saving to the repository:

INSERT INTO financialchangetags (id, tagId, financialChangeId) VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT)

Comment: An additional row was always added regardless of what was going on for some reason and I still have no clue - It's driving me nuts.